# How to generate a sequence code string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model which has a column named `code`, which is a combination of the model's name column and its ID with leading zeros.

```
name = 'Rocky'
id = 16
```

I have an `after_create` callback which runs and generates the code:

```
update(code: "#{self.name[0..2].upcase}%.4d" % self.id)
```

The generated code will be:

```
"ROC0016"
```

The code is working.

I found  `(%.4d" % self.id)` from another project, but I don't know how it works.

How does it determine the number of zeros to be preceded based on the passed integer.

Comment: See [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) and [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Comment: This code is actually prone to collisions. When you get past `id = 10001` the generated codes will start colliding with codes with the same name and truncated id. For example `{ id: 333, name: 'max' }` and `{ id: 10333, name: 'max' }` both give `MAX_0333`.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. DId you research and read the documentation? It's well explained. "[“Explain X to me” questions: How to react?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/)"

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you. It helped. I was exactly looking for something like this.

Comment: @max It's just an example length for demonstration. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the guide. I searched around google to find the string code generator in the sequence but there wasn't mush out there. With the help of this question, I did find many helpful links. 
I'll keep in mind the guide before asking the next question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You’re using a "format specifier". There are many specifiers, but the one you’re using, `"%d"`, is the decimal specifier:

`%` starts it.  `4` means it should always use at least four numbers, so if the number is only two digits, it gets padded with `0`s to fill in the rest of the numbers. The second `%` means replace `4d` with whatever comes after it. So in your case,  `4d` is getting replaced with `"0016"`.

[`sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) has more information about format specifiers.

You can read more about [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-25) in the documentation also.

Comment: And the `%` is the [String#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) method.

Answer (score 1):

After the percentage sign ("`%`") is a decimal (`"."`) and a number. That number is the number of total digits in the result. If the result is less than this value, additional zeros will be added.

Thus, in this first example, the result is "34" but length was set to "`4`". The result will have two leading zeros to fill it into four digits.

```
"This is test string %.4d" % 34
result => "This is test string 0034"

"I want more zeroes in my code %.7d" % 34
result => "I want more zeroes in my code 0000034"
```